# Bug in .NET framework, reference hidden member using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, frameworks, .net-core

I am thinking that there should be a bug in .NET framework as per the specifications "when we refer object directly instead of using the parent reference it should call the hidden member".
For the same scenario I have used generics but it was not supported for more understanding please go through the code and the output for your reference.
Example code be find here.

```
public class A
{
  public A()
  {
      Console.WriteLine("A ctor called");
      Property=111;
  }
  public int Property { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B ctor called");
        Property=222;
    }
    public int Property { get; set; }
}
```

-----With out Generics-----------

```
 public class Caller
{
    public virtual int Property { get; set; }
    public Caller()
    {
        Property=4444;
    }
    public A GetDevice()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
public class NextCaller:Caller
{
    public NextCaller()
    {
        Property=5464654;
    }
    public new B GetDevice()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}

 -----With Generics-----------

public interface ReferenceType<TType> where TType:Caller
{
    TType GetCurrentType();
}
public class Handler<TType>:ReferenceType<TType> where TType:Caller
{
    public virtual TType CurrentObj {get;set;}
    public virtual TType GetCurrentType()
    {
        return CurrentObj as TType;
    } 
    public virtual void Show()
    {
        var type=GetCurrentType();
         Console.WriteLine(CurrentObj.Property);
        Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentType().GetDevice().Property);
    }
}
public class HandlerNext<TType> : Handler<TType> where TType:NextCaller
{
    public override TType CurrentObj {get;set;}
    public override TType GetCurrentType()
    {
        return CurrentObj;
    }
}
```

-------Usage Demo-------------------

```
public class UsageDemo
{
    public void Main()
    {
        //using generics 
        var handler=new Handler<Caller>();
        handler.CurrentObj=new NextCaller();
        handler.Show();
        var handler1=new HandlerNext<NextCaller>();
        handler1.CurrentObj=new NextCaller();
        handler1.Show();         

        //with out using generics 
        Caller handle=new NextCaller();
        Console.WriteLine(handle.GetDevice().Property);
        NextCaller handle1=new NextCaller();
        Console.WriteLine(handle1.GetDevice().Property);
    }
}
```

### Output:-

//using generics 
A ctor calledenter code here
111
A ctor called
111
//with out using generics 
A ctor called
111
B ctor called
222

Problem here is, 
out of those four outputs 2nd out put showing the wrong result because I have deduce the results using generics. If we see result in the output without using the generics it working correctly (refer output 4).
As per the specifications when we refer object directly instead of using the parent reference it should call the hidden member.
The above specification is not working when we use generics.

Answer (score 0):

Because your show method is in the `Handler<TType>`, it can only access methods and properties of the type Caller because of the `:Caller` constaint.  It cannot access methods from the type NextCaller.

If you create an override for the `.Show` method in the `HandlerNext` class with the exact same method body, it will call methods based on the NextCaller type because of the `:NextCaller` constraint on that class.

Comment: Yes. It is correct but when we debug it is showing the NextCaller Object in  CurrentObj  property the Handler<TType> class. Basically my concept is to call the hidden member using the same reference.

Comment: The object in the CurrentObj property is a NextCaller object, but your .Show method is implemented in the base Handler class, which treats it like a Caller object.  Since it is treating it like a Caller object, it calls your hidden GetDevice method from the Caller object instead of the GetDevice method from the NextCaller object.